# how to disable bootstrap toggle button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, knockout.js, togglebutton

I am trying to disable bootstrap toggle buttons but no luck yet

```
   <div class="toggle btn btn-default" disabled data-toggle="toggle" data-bind="toggle:isok(), css:{off:!isok()}">
                        <div class="toggle-group">
                            <label  class="btn btn-primary toggle-on">ON</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-default active toggle-off">OFF</label>
                            <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I am using knockout to bind data. I hardcoded to add disabled property as you can see but it shows as disabled but i still can make it on or off.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hardcoded the `disabled` attribute to a `div` element. A div can't be disabled. Change the div to a `button` and it will work, see the example below in which the toggle has been handcrafted:

```js
function Test() {
  var _this = this;
  _this.disabled = ko.observable();
  _this.active = ko.observable();

  _this.toggleActive = function() {
    _this.active(!_this.active());
  }

  _this.toggleDisable = function() {
    _this.disabled(!_this.disabled());
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new Test());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" data-bind="css: {active: active}, click: toggleActive, enable: disabled">
      <span data-bind="visible: active">ON</span>
      <span data-bind="visible: !active()">OFF</span>
    </button>

<a href="#" data-bind="click: toggleDisable">toggle disable</a>
```

Comment: how can i convert div to button? i already have 2 labels inside that div which are on and off. can you modify my part of code and tell me how to do it?

Comment: The example has been modified. The ON and OFF label visibility as well as the button toggle state (active-class) is updated according to the current toggle state.

Comment: you have used click even called toggleDisable. Not sure what i use in my case

Comment: It is there to demonstrate how to enable/disable the button with knockout.That's what the original question is all about, right?

Comment: yes offcourse that was my original question but i am not sure how i disable it with all this setup that i have. its very confusing this toggle button

Comment: I hope my example is of any help. The active observable in the example maps to your isok observable. You should add a disabled observable to your viewmodel. Make sure also to remove data-toggle="toggle" from the button.

Comment: many many many thanks. Only change i had to do is to change div tag to button tag and thats it. I already had enable tag on my div which i didnt show i didnt posted in my question